# Getting AngularJS Scope in Nightwatch

Tags: angularjs, scope

I am new to Nightwatch, and I am just wondering how to get an AngularJS element scoped in Nightwatch.

Is there any way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Please , describe more better your question, put some code as example because tour question is not o clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
    const getElementScope = (selector) => {
        cy.get(selector)
            .then(($el) => { 
                cy.window()
                .its('angular')
                .then((ng) => {
                    console.log(ng.element($el).scope())
                    console.log("ng.element($el)", ng.element($el))
                })
            })
    }
```

In cypress we can get angular scope like so is there any way to get angular scope.

I tried below 2, but it says scope and angular is not a function:

```
  1)browser.execute(function(){
      return $('#maincontent > div.container-fluid').scope();
    }, ['title'], function(result){
      console.log(result)
    });

  2)browser.execute(function(){
      return angular.element($('#maincontent > div.container-fluid')).scope();
    }, ['title'], function(result){
      console.log(result)
    });
```